# I need clarification on the ThreadpoolExecutor beforeExecute and afterExecute hooks 

Tags: java, multithreading, executors

I am using threadpools in my application. I have subclassed the TreadPoolExecutor and overriden the methods beforeExecute, afterExecute and terminated for statistical purposes.
I also have implemented my own ThreadFactory and overriden the newThread method.

I understand that the threadpool wrapper class creates a dozen of "callable" tasks and calls the invokeAll method to get the results. In each task there is an interface object. The base X object implements the interface and has been subclassed a number of times. So when the threadpool is executed it launches childs of the object X.

From a code perspective it looks a bit like:

```
the wrapper threapool class:

List<DoTask> tasks;     

tasks.add(new DoTask(new A("A"));
tasks.add(new DoTask(new B("B"));
tasks.add(new DoTask(new C("C"));

results = threadpool.invokeAll(tasks, 60, TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

---

```
in my DoTask class: public DoTask implements Callable

constructor: DoTask(ifaceX x)
```

---

```
im my Base class X: public class X implements ifaceX
In my child class A, B, C: public A extends X
```

My questions is, how to retrieve information kept in the callable task when I call the before and after execute hooks? or I guess what I am trying to do is give a specific name to each thread of the threadpool is that possible?

I can clearly see the information is there in the Eclipse variables view in debug mode hidden in the Runnable object/FutureTask/callable.

I do not understand why I only have to override methods (beforeExecute, afterExecute) with Runnable objects and no Callable ones (since I need to retrieve results). Something I am missing or do not understand? Maybe I need to subclass FutureTask not sure?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to superclass `DoTask` if you want things to happen before and after each call instead of overriding `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute`.

Edit: Also, if you're using callables, you might want to use an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: I believe he's asking about how before/afterExecute() handle Callable tasks instead of Runnable ones?